# Deprecated Functionality: usort(): Returning bool from comparison function is deprecated, return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero

Tags: return, php-8, usort, spaceship-operator

Ran into a slight issue here below with some of my code.

```
// sorting
$sortField = $this->sortField;
$sortDir = $this->sortDir;
usort($data, function ($a, $b) use ($sortField, $sortDir) {
    if ($sortDir == "asc") {
        return $a[$sortField] > $b[$sortField];
    } else {
        return $a[$sortField] < $b[$sortField];
    }
});
```

A bit confused here on what i need to change.

I read this in another thread.

PHP 8 introduced the Stable Sorting RFC, which (as it sounds) means that all sorting functions in PHP are now "stable".

The spaceship operator is used for comparing two expressions. It returns -1, 0 or 1 when $a is respectively less than, equal to, or greater than $b. Comparisons are performed according to PHP's usual type comparison rules.

So does this mean I need to add the spaceship operator here in the returns:

```
        return $a[$sortField] <=> $b[$sortField];
    } else {
        return $a[$sortField] <=> $b[$sortField];
    }
```

That is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I, personally, haven't used that operator, but yeah since you need the return to be 1, 0, or -1.  But you will want to reverse the left and right so it behaves correctly based on sort order.  Like so:

```
if ($sortDir == "asc") {
    return $a[$sortField] <=> $b[$sortField];
} else {
    return $b[$sortField] <=> $a[$sortField];
}
```

I just got this error on an older website with the error stating the functionality was "deprecated"  Ha!  It caused the api call to fail completely, so I think we are past "deprecated", don't ya think? :-)

Also, I may have your logic backwards, but I think you should get the drift.

Hope that helps.